# Why i cant navigate to a static Html page in my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I have an azure app service. I have a few html and .aspx pages.
I would particularly like to be able to navigate to the .html page.
But when i go to the uri in the browser i get this error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Q) What must i do to allow navigation to such static pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access static .html pages hosted by the app service, you need to do some config for its path. For Windows app service, you can create a virtual directory, for containerized app service, you will need to mount a storage account. Details see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-path-mappings).

Comment: The app service project has an Index.html file at the root. Would i still need a virtual directory or setup a path map for a default page at the root level?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar exactly,but if you place your index.html in a new folder under root and map this new folder as a virtual directory would be better, exposing root to the public network is dangerous